# Popup From TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, popup, uitabbar

I currently have a tabbar with 5 objects. **What I am trying to do is if the user presses the third object a pop up will go over their current screen and not move them to another screen.** Then once the user presses on one of the popups it will move them to the next screen. I currently can not make this popup happen. How do I do this? I made a view in sketch to show you what I mean (the popups have the red box around them):
[image: Example]

I tried to change the segue between object 3 and its view controller but it did not work because for object 3 to even show up on the tabbar, you need a "Relationship Segue: view controllers". For the pop up to happen I need a Present Modally segue (the type of segue I do for my in view controller segues). So if I do a Present Modally segue, instead of a "Relationship Segue: view controllers" from the tabbar controller to the controller with my pop ups, I will not have "object 3" and will only have 4 tabbar icons instead of 5.

----Edit---- @Flickerlight's logic:

`

```
import UIKit

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
let tbh = TabBarHandler()

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
class TabBarHandler: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate{
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        let vcIndex = tabBarController.viewControllers!.index(of: viewController)!
        if  vcIndex == 2 {
            let button1 = UIButton()
            button1.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
            button1.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

            let button2 = UIButton()
            button2.setTitle("Settings", for: .normal)
            button2.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingButtonPresssed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [button1,button2])
            sv.distribution = .equalSpacing

            let currentView = tabBarController.selectedViewController!.view!
            sv.frame = CGRect(x: currentView.bounds.midX - 80, y: currentView.bounds.midY + 150, width: 160, height: 40)
            currentView.addSubview(sv)
            currentView.bringSubview(toFront: sv)
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }

    @objc func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender:UIButton) {
        if let parentStackView = sender.superview as? UIStackView {
            parentStackView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    @objc func settingButtonPresssed(_ sender:UIButton){
        if let parentStackView = sender.superview as? UIStackView {
            parentStackView.removeFromSuperview()
            if let tabBC = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                tabBC.selectedIndex = 2
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

In my first view controller's viewDidLoad:

`self.tabBarController?.delegate = tbh`

In tabBarController:

```
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1 {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well..It is clearer now. I have no code regarding tabBarController as your last part. Why did you implement shouldSelect methods twice in different place? Remove the last part and try again.

Answer (score 6):

My thinking is that you can implement your [UITabbarControllerdelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate) and utilize the ["shouldSelect"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621166-tabbarcontroller) method.

In this method,

1.check whether current item to be selected is the third one.

2.If so, show your popup, and return false to keep the tab remain on current view.

3.In your popup buttonPressed methods, implement the selection of corresponding tab programmatically.

---

Updated:

Keypoint, you need to programmatically instruct the tabbarcontroller to go to your view.

Tried in my project with buttons solution (as you wish), below code works.

```
let tbh = tabbarHandler()

class tabbarHandler:NSObject,UITabBarControllerDelegate{
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        let vcIndex = tabBarController.viewControllers!.index(of: viewController)!
        if  vcIndex == 2 {
            let button1 = UIButton()
            button1.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
            button1.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

            let button2 = UIButton()
            button2.setTitle("Settings", for: .normal)
            button2.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingButtonPresssed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [button1,button2])
            sv.distribution = .equalSpacing

            let currentView = tabBarController.selectedViewController!.view!
            sv.frame = CGRect(x: currentView.bounds.midX - 80, y: currentView.bounds.midY + 150, width: 160, height: 40)
            currentView.addSubview(sv)
            currentView.bringSubview(toFront: sv)
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }

    @objc func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender:UIButton) {
        if let parentStackView = sender.superview as? UIStackView {
            parentStackView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    @objc func settingButtonPresssed(_ sender:UIButton){
        if let parentStackView = sender.superview as? UIStackView {
            parentStackView.removeFromSuperview()
            if let tabBC = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                tabBC.selectedIndex = 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do remember to  initialize the delegate object and assign your tabbarController's delegate to it.

In my attempt, I init the object as a global variable, and attach it to tabbarController in my first view's viewDidLoad():

```
self.tabBarController?.delegate = tbh
```

The result screenshot on my iphone as below.
When I press the third tabbar item, two buttons will be displayed: press "cancel" to stay, press "Settings" to show the third view.

I just use a straightforward way to illustrate the idea, sure you can polish the appearance to be prettier.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I implemented the UITabbarControllerdelegate in my UITabBarController class with the "shouldSelect" method, but I can not figure out how to tell which item is selected. I tried to print the view controller selected but it does not give me value. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try cast the "shouldSelect" viewController to your viewController. Something like:  if let vcToSelect = shouldSelect as? Your3rdVC { //show your popup and return false}

Comment: Please skip my previous comment. Actually I just realize that the "shouldSelect" view controller for tabbar controller often is a UINavigationController, which cannot be casted to your VC.The updated answer works with alert controller, and it should be also easy to implement a button version.

Comment: is there a way to get this in the style I want (in the picture)?

Comment: also I just implemented this code and the alert did not show up. How do I fix this if it is not possible to get the type of popup I want?

Comment: Don't forget to set delegate of your tabBarController. And updated a button vision.

Comment: I made a new NSObject class and copied your code in to test it out. I also placed in a view's viewDidLoad the `self.tabBarController?.delegate = tbh`. Then I went to go press the tabbar item and nothing popped up. **What did I miss?**

Comment: I would suspect that the object initialization or your delegate assignment is not executed before you press. You can set breakpoint to see the process flow step by step.

Comment: How will I do this exactly?

Comment: There should be plenty of articles about how to debug in Xcode if you do google search. For example this one: https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/xcode-debugging-with-breakpoints-for-beginners-5b0d0a39d711. But as where to set the breakpoints, it depends on your comprehension of your code architecture and control flow...

Comment: I will love to use this but I do not know why this is not working. I am not sure what to do. I have a NSObject with you code and I have put the tabbar delegate in my first view's viewDidload code: `if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            self.tabBarController?.delegate = tbh
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }` What can I do next to fix this???

Comment: I use UIStackview to quickly organize the two buttons in my example, which requires ios 9.0+.What's your target ios version? if prior ios 9, you should remove UIStackview related code and put the buttons to exactly the places you want.

Comment: my target iOS 10 so using a UIStackview could work. But when I entered your code, the UIStackview was already in the code. Is their something else I need to add or missing? I really want to figure this out so if you need me to show you anything for better understanding let me know.

Comment: I dont' quite understand...What does it mean by "the UIStackview was already in the code"? Did xcode give any complain or runtime error? Did you set breakpoints to see how the control flow goes and whether the "shouldSelect" method was ever entered? I cannot tell how to debug  your code because I have no idea of how your code is organized...

Comment: Btw, if your target is only ios10(and above), then I don't see any necessity for the code snippet as "if #avaiable(ios 9.0,*) ...".

Comment: I was using the code provided by you to implement this in. Is there something more than your code I should add? So everything I have comes from what you sent, if there’s anything I should add let me know. Also the if iOS 9 is available came from Xcode making me add it

Comment: These are all what I did in my app for displaying the effect. You should understand that: the uncertainty here is your code structure may be different to mine,so the timing to set tab bar controller delegate may be different, and also that's why I ask you to debug with breakpoints to see whether the delegate indeed was called to execute the shouldSelect method. Did you try?

Comment: yeah I added break points to my the tabBar `shouldSelect` method at the `if` and `else`: `func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1 {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }` and none of them were called and I am not sure why

Comment: I have edited my post to show you what I have coded so far